# tier prices / configurable Products - doesnt work

Tags: magento

im using Magento 1.8.0.0.

Im offering configurable Products with different Flavours

For Example:
My products is available in Vanilla and chocolate.

1x item 50€
2x items 45€

When the customer choose 2x Vanilla - he get the Price of 45€/Piece. But if he choose 1x Vanilla and 1x Chocolate he have to pay 50/Piece.

Can anyone tell me - how i can fix this Problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tier price was made for selling packs of simple products.
I suggest you to take a look at Shopping cart price rules.
They are more flexible in configuration.